# How to add JButtons in a for loop?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, minecraft, bukkit

So I am making an UI in a minecraft plugin, and it adds a button for every player, and when we click the button, it kicks the player.
This is the for loop:

```
for (final Player p : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers())
    {
        System.out.println("Looping.");
        final JButton b = new JButton();
        b.setName(p.getName());
        b.setText(p.getName());
        b.setToolTipText("Kick " + b.getText());
        b.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (!b.getBackground().equals(Color.RED))
                {
                        Bukkit.getScheduler().runTask(main, new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                Bukkit.getPlayer(b.getText()).kickPlayer(jtf.getText());
                            b.setBackground(Color.RED);
                            }
                        });
                }

            }
        });
        System.out.println("Button added.");
        f.add(b);
    }
```

And let's say there are 2 players in the server, **asd** and **dsa**. When this for loop runs, it just adds button for **asd**, but prints **Button added** (and **Looping**) two times.

(**f** is a **public static JFrame**, and **jtf** is a **public static JTextField**)

So... Why is it not working?

Comment: In your code, I can't find any link to your `Player p`. Do you use it? Because of that, it uses an only first player in an array, I suppose

Comment: I edited it, f is JFrame and jtf is JTextField

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger and how do I use the JPanel to fill the whole JFrame (even if we scale the window)?

Comment: "and how do I use the JPanel to fill the whole JFrame (even if we scale the window)" - did you try ?  If you did and have questions about it, please post a new question.

Comment: Okay so this is solved, I just posted a new question about my new problem.

Answer (score 1):

It happens because the defult `LayoutManager` is `BorderLayout`, so the method `add(JComponent comp)` puts the `JComponent` in the center of the `JFrame`, and the `JComponent` fills the entire `JFrame`.
Use the method `f.setLayout(new GridLayout(number_of_players, 1));`, it will split the `JFrmae` to rows as the number of your players, so a multiply number of `JComponents` could be displayed.